# Angular 1.5 create a table avoiding duplicate values

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to create a table I have the following code

```
<tr ng-repeat="value in sd.data>
   <td >{{value.syscode}}</td>
   <td>{{value.out_signal_id}}</td>
   <td>{{value.sig_epoch_utc}}</td>
   <td>{{value.num_of_signals}}</td>
   <td>{{value.status_code}}</td>
   <td>{{value.status_note}}</td>


  <tr >
```

This is an example how the table looks like after the array has been looped by ng-repeat

```
syscode | out_signal_id  | sig_epoch_utc | num_of_signals | status_code | status_note


2221111 |   12323454343  | 2093236693029 | 120000000000   | 3030000000|  no-errors

2221111 |   12323454343  | 2093235593029 | 120000000000   | 3030000000| no-errors-1

2221111 |   12323454343  | 2093233393029 | 120000000000   | 3030000000| no-errors-2
```

I am trying to skip the repeated values on 'syscode' in this case I just need only one '2221111' not 3 of them, I did look through other answers for questions similar to this one, but that didn't answer my question. Any answer will be appreciated thanks!

Comment: Do you care about which version of `status_note` gets displayed?

Comment: In the first column use the rowspan attribute.

Comment: @WhiteHotLoveTiger all of the status_note values have to rendered, the only values not to be displayed are the repeated values for syscode, but the order doesn't matter if that is what you are asking, it doesn't matter if status_note is in order or not

Comment: Ok, so you still want all three rows displayed, but with the first column only getting printed the first time if there's duplicates in that column?

Comment: @WhiteHotLoveTiger Yes that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working plunker:
https://plnkr.co/edit/zWXR7k2H9hMwza5H2ZfU?p=preview

I'm making the assumption that the rows will be sorted based on syscode and all rows with same syscode will be adjacent.

Track the ng-repeat by $index `ng-repeat="value in sd.data track by $index"` and compare the value of the syscode in the current row to the previous row. If it is the same, display blank value.
`<td>{{($index>0 && sd.data[$index].syscode === sd.data[$index-1].syscode) ? '' : value.syscode}}</td>`

Answer (score 1):

If the status note will always be 'no-errors' and that is the row of data you want, then this can be easily fixed with an `ng-if` directive. Otherwise, i'd recommend filtering the dataset and removing repeat values and putting that array on the scope or creating a filter.

```
<tr ng-repeat="value in sd.data" ng-if="value.status_note === 'no-errors'>
   <td >{{value.syscode}}</td>
   <td>{{value.out_signal_id}}</td>
   <td>{{value.sig_epoch_utc}}</td>
   <td>{{value.num_of_signals}}</td>
   <td>{{value.status_code}}</td>
   <td>{{value.status_note}}</td>
  <tr >
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a 'unique' filter on the `syscode` attribute. You'll have to get Angular-UI:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui/0.4.0/angular-ui.js"></script>
```

Add it as a module dependency:

```
var app = angular.module('yourProjectName', ['ui.filters']);
```

Then specify the filter:

```
<tr ng-repeat="value in sd.data | unique:'syscode'" >
```